# Does set insertion invalidates for each loop?

Tags: c++, foreach, insert, set, invalidation

Let's look at the following example:

```
    set<int> candidates;
    for (int candidate : candidates) {
      if (candidate == target) {
        candidates.erase(target);
      }
    }
```

I would like to know if the iterators gets invalidated, and wonder if it does affect the for-each loop.

because according to the standards, **in the insert function it says**:

> No iterators or references are invalidated.
>
> > If the insertion is successful, pointers and references to the element obtained while it is held in the node handle are invalidated, and pointers and references obtained to that element before it was extracted become valid. (since C++17)

Comment: You looked at `insert`, but you are calling `erase`.

Comment: If inserting is actually what you're talking about, take a look at [How do we iterate through all elements of a set while inserting new elements to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1547066/10077).

Comment: Also note that if erasing is what you're talking about, the whole loop should be replaced with just `candidates.erase(target);`, which will be safe (no invalidated iterators) and efficient (O(log n) instead of O(n)).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if the iterators gets invalidated,

Yes. `std::set::erase` invalidates iterators to the erased element.

> and wonder if it does affect the for-each loop.

Yes. The behaviour is undefined if the `erase` is called in the example.

---

The loop is entirely unnecessary. You can instead use just a single call to `candidates.erase(target)`.

---

> according to the standards, in the insert function it says:

What the standard says about insert function is largely irrelevant when you don't insert.